# Uploading file to assistants api OpenAI

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api

What I am trying to do is create a little chatbot that uses a `.txt` file as a knowledge source. I've got this code:

```py
my_thread_message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
    thread_id=my_thread.id,
    role="user",
    content=user_input,
    file_ids=[file_id]
)
```

which is supposed to attach the `file_id`, which I've **confirmed** is already uploaded via the OpenAI dashboard. I've copied the ID right from there and put it into my variable called `file_id`. However, when I run my code - I receive the following message:

> I can't access the file you uploaded to provide details on our pricing. If you can provide the information or specify your request differently, I'd be happy to assist with pricing details or any other questions you may have.

I want to confirm that I'm attaching the `file_id` correctly, as a list. The code in its entirety is as follows:

```py
try:
    # Create a new thread
    my_thread = client.beta.threads.create()
except Exception as e:
    console.print(f"Failed to create a new thread: {e}", style="bold red")
    exit(1)

# Loop until the user enters "quit"
while True:
    # Get user input
    user_input = input("User: ")

    # Check if the user wants to quit
    if user_input.lower() == "quit":
        console.print("\nAssistant: Have a nice day! :wave:", style="black on white")
        break

    try:
        # Add user message to the thread
        my_thread_message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
            thread_id=my_thread.id, role="user", content=user_input, file_ids=[file_id]
        )
    except Exception as e:
        console.print(f"Failed to add message to thread: {e}", style="bold red")
        continue  # Skip further processing and prompt for next input

    try:
        # Run the assistant
        my_run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(
            thread_id=my_thread.id,
            assistant_id=assistant_id,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        console.print(f"Failed to initiate assistant run: {e}", style="bold red")
        continue

    # Initial delay before the first retrieval
    time.sleep(2)

    try:
        # Periodically retrieve the run to check its status
        while True:
            keep_retrieving_run = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(
                thread_id=my_thread.id, run_id=my_run.id
            )

            if keep_retrieving_run.status == "completed":
                # Retrieve the messages added by the assistant to the thread
                all_messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=my_thread.id)

                # Display assistant message
                if all_messages.data:
                    console.print(
                        f"\nAssistant: {all_messages.data[0].content[0].text.value}\n",
                        style="black on white",
                    )
                else:
                    console.print(
                        "\nAssistant: No response received.", style="bold red"
                    )
                break
            elif keep_retrieving_run.status in ["queued", "in_progress"]:
                # Delay before the next retrieval attempt
                time.sleep(2)
            else:
                console.print(
                    f"\nAssistant run failed with status: {keep_retrieving_run.status}",
                    style="bold red",
                )
                break
    except Exception as e:
        console.print(
            f"Error during run retrieval or message display: {e}", style="bold red"
        )
```

Any advice?

Comment: At the official community forum of OpenAI, there are reports (Nov. 2023 to Dec. 2023) that similar situations happened and resolved over time. See [The Assistants API cannot access files for some reason](https://community.openai.com/t/the-assistants-api-cannot-access-files-for-some-reason/525243).